Help me I'm installing Ubuntu 24.04 lts and now it's have a proplem
I it's say the code sudo Ubuntu -bug Ubuntu -desktop -bootstraps

What is the exact error message you're seeing? Are you able to take a picture or screenshot and share it here?
